# Show elements outside browser viewport

Tags: css, browser, development-environment

Is there any way or workflow that will allow you to see elements that are positioned partially (or wholly) outside the viewport of the browser while designing? Like you can with artboards in Illustrator?

For example: Say I have a rectangle positioned at {left: -50px} in the body (that's a minus in there), meaning that 50px worth of rectangle is outside the viewport. Is there any tool that will visually represent that?

Comment: can you post a picture of what you want, its sorta hard to visualize

Comment: A hack solution: Create a `div` with `width:75%; display:block, margin:auto` and put your entire page into it. The things thatoverflow will land into the body as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it stands, your question appears to be off-topic, as it's asking for a resource of some kind ("*Is there any tool...*"), instead of asking a programming question. I'm sorry, but [we don't do 'shopping.'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Here is what I meant btw: https://jsfiddle.net/5b430qrr/

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you I've rephrased the question.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin If you post your question as an answer I'd be ready to accept it! (Generally designing within a temporary div kinda seems like a cool thing to try if you need to do responsive designs with things positioned outside the view. You could make a div at say 75% height and width of viewport and then drag to resize the browser window as normal. And know exactly how all the elements outside of the viewport behaves when the screen resizes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A hack solution](https://jsfiddle.net/5b430qrr/): Create a `div` to contain all the content of your website, but make the `width < 100%` so that you can see the content as it overflows into the `body`. Change the width as you like..

```
<div class="virtualize-overflow">
  Normal Content
  <div class="overflow">Overflowing content</div>
</div>

.virtualize-overflow{
  display:block;
  background-color:gray;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:30%;
}

.overflow{
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```